# Vuelidate vue.js latest for vue3 using the helpers.forEach approach for array of objects

Tags: vuejs3, vuelidate

Using Vuelidate vue.js latest for vue3 using the `helpers.forEach` approach for array of objects. I tried running the form but the validation is causing an error given as the below

> Gives $response.$errors is undefined in the console
> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $response.$errors is undefined

```
export default {
  setup () {
    const rules = {
      collection: {
        $each: helpers.forEach({
          name: {
            required
          }
        })
      }
    }
    const state = reactive({
      collection: [
        { name: '' },
      ]
    })
    const v = useVuelidate(rules, state)
    return { v, state }
}
}
```

This is the template of the code

```
  <div
    v-for="(input, index) in state.collection"
    :key="index"
    :class="{
        error: v$.collection.$each.$response.$errors[index].name.length,
      }"
  >
    <input v-model="input.name" type="text" />
    <div
      v-for="error in v$.collection.$each.$response.$errors[index].name"
      :key="error"
    >
      {{ error.$message }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Dúvida semelhante a essa resposta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74567499/13589774

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to use v$ as this was v$ represented a global variable based on useVuelidate

Answer (score 0):

Little late, but in your template you are refering to `v$.collection` instead of `v.collection`. In your setup you are returning `v` and not `v$`